# How to get the name in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.AccountList}" var="ac">
  <div class="tileLabel" id="{!ac.Id}" aura:id="acId" onclick=" 
{!c.handleClick}">{!ac.Name}</div> 
   </div>
```

In javascript, I need id as well as name {!ac.name}

```
    ({    
          handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        var accountId = event.target.id; //Id i will get here & how to get name 

}
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just "find" the entire account record, which is usually more practical anyways:

```
var account = component.get("v.AccountList")
              .find(record => record.Id === event.target.id);
```

You now have access to `account.Id`, `account.Name`, and whatever other fields you may have queried or used for input.

Comment: this soultion works any number of the fields.i really like this solution.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The one Tushar mentioned would work, But am not big fan of using innerHTML.

What you can do is define an attribute named as name in your div.

```
<div class="tileLabel" id="{!ac.Id}" aura:id="acId" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" name="{!ac.name}">
    {!ac.Name} 
</div>
```

and then JS just access it as

```
({    
          handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
                var accountId = event.target.id; //Id i will get here 
                var accountName = event.target.name;

        }
))
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is HTML element so plain JavaScript will work here. You can simply get the inner content of div using below script.

```
var accName = document.getElementById(accountId).innerHTML
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use getElementById as if you ever have a component with that an html attribute with the same id on the same page they will conflict with one another

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe Here Id is unique so this will work. Also as a best practice, we keep id unique. Based on the current situation this solution will work.

Comment: @TusharSharma You are partially correct, in this component the Id is unique but if another developer were to create a different lightning component and give an attribute the same Id and then they were to add the component to the same page it would break this functionality.  I'm not doubting it works currently it just adds unnecessary instability to the component long term.  getElementById breaks out of the scope of the lightning component and searches the entire page, which goes against the component aspect of Lightning Development.